# Oracle APEX_ITEM API usage and issues

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-apex

I have the following select statement that I am using as a standard report:

```
select id,
       name,
       telephone,
       apex_item.checkbox2(10,id) as "Tick when Contacted",
       apex_item.text(20,:P2_DATE) as "Date Contacted",
       apex_item.textarea(30,:P2_COMMENT,5,80) as "Comment"
from   my_table
```

My question is and the area that I am not sure if I am doing this correctly is that if this statement returns 10 rows and out of those 10 rows, I only select/check 5 records and then press the submit button, why is it that my PL/SQL page process that inserts the selected records into another table is not picking up `:P2_DATE` and `:P2_COMMENT` which are hidden items on the page and purely just used as placeholders and not actual columns within my_table?

Am I doing this correctly or do I need to use an apex collection?

Here is what my page process looks like; is this correct?

```
DECLARE

  v_row          BINARY_INTEGER;

BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..APEX_APPLICATION.G_F10.COUNT LOOP
    v_row := APEX_APPLICATION.G_F10(i);

    INSERT INTO MY_OTHER_TABLE
                   ( DATE_CONTACTED,
                     COMMENTS 
                   )
    VALUES         ( APEX_APPLICATION.G_F20(v_row),
                     APEX_APPLICATION.G_F30(v_row) 
                   );
  END LOOP;

  COMMIT;
END;
```

Example of report with user input is as follows:

```
ID/CHECKBOX         DATE CONTACTED          COMMENTS
=====================================================
1                   21/08/2012              Comment 1
2                   21/08/2012              Comment 2
3                   21/08/2012              Comment 3
4                   21/08/2012              Comment 4
5                   21/08/2012              Comment 5
```

Based on this report where user has manually entered these 5 comments, I expect these 5 records get inserted into MY_OTHER_TABLE, as they have been checked.

Unfortunately MY_OTHER_TABLE never gets populated for the 5 records that I have checked.

I am unsure what I have missed out on something, or if I have completely got my original select wrong with regards to using these two placeholder items?

Comment: You use these items to provide a default value i take it? What is the source for the items? Can you run a debug of the page on show and on save, and see if the value of these changes?

Comment: add this line of code in your processing process, in your loop: `apex_debug_message.log_message('Processing item '||APEX_APPLICATION.G_F10(i););` and see what happens in the debug.

Comment: Tom: From my debugging of my page process and printing out v_row for the 5 checked records, I am actually receiving the the correct id values. P2_DATE and P2_COMMENT are NULL and source is what the user is actually typing into these items on the page. P2_DATE is set via javascript and the comment is what the user enters. I then want to capture this information and store within MY_OTHER_TABLE. Am I doing this correctly? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think i understand quite correctly yet. Your report (10recs) have input fields, editable by user. What role exactly do these 2 extra items play? Do they serve as a default value? You don't these values in the processing? When you debug and you put out the values for f20 and f30, do these show values? (they should)

Comment: I guess Tom my question to you is, can I user apex_item.text api where the source is not coming from an underlying oracle table? If not then how can I capture values on the fly based on user input for multiple record inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your comment you say

> can I user apex_item.text api where the source is not coming from an underlying oracle table?

Now i read that as:

> can i generate this report and have the **default value** for my apex_item fields set to that of my 2 page items.

Yes. You can. That is what i thought you meant originallyn and it makes sense since the items are hidden anyway. Just make sure of the below:
if you meant that the value is not put in the report items at page load:
if the region with the hidden items is BELOW the region with your report, move your region with the items or create a new region ABOVE the region with your report.
With above and below i'm talking about their position in the form structure. Switch over to tree view if you use component view to easily see this.
My guess is that the item (and its source) is processed before, and thus has a valid session state before the rendering of the report starts.

Comment: I edited a bit, but i'm not sure we're actually on the same page yet ;)